# rsync slash in dir name

Tags: linux, macos, rsync, nas

I'm backing up 12TB of files from MacOS to linux (synology nas) where some of the directories contain slashes.
These directories are renamed to something like `4XQVKM~V`on the nas.
Is there a way to avoid this with rsync?
If not, what's the best way to rename all folders containing slashes?

Comment: Hm, since a slash in a file name is invalid in Unix philosophy I doubt there is a way. It would leave you with a _broken_ backup, unusable files.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems the OSX allows slashes in directory/file names, linux does not. You can either rename all of the files/folders before you rsync them over, change the names after they've been rsync'd, or just accept them the way they are.

If you're looking to change the filenames before you run rsync, [this thread might be useful.](https://superuser.com/questions/617517/remove-all-illegal-characters-from-all-filenames-in-a-given-folder)